# error thrown on successful saveChanges() call [breezeJS]

Tags: angularjs, runtime-error, odata, breeze

I use breeze.angular to communicate with an olingo OData provider. After changing properties of an Entity I have a pending change. The corresponding object is visible when `manager.getChanges()` is called.

Calling `manager.saveChanges` in fact results in successful update of the database through olingo. But simultaneously the following error gets thrown:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'entityAspect' of undefined
    at http://localhost:63342/js/breeze.debug.js:14471:38
    at http://localhost:63342js/breeze.debug.js:258:26
    at Array.map (native)
    at __map (http://localhost:63342js/breeze.debug.js:257:15)
    at proto.visitAndMerge (http://localhost:63342/js/breeze.debug.js:14470:16)
    at http://localhost:63342/js/breeze.debug.js:13102:48
    at __using (http://localhost:63342/js/breeze.debug.js:423:16)
    at Object.processSavedEntities (http://localhost:63342/js/breeze.debug.js:13091:13)
    at saveSuccess (http://localhost:63342/js/breeze.debug.js:13070:67)
    at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:63342/js/angular.js:11319:81)
```

Apparently breeze is unable to change the entityState, as the objects remain pending changes.

Regarding the http communication I observed two Server requests:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
```

and

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:202 Accepted
```

Why is breeze unable to transact this succesful update?

---

UPDATE:
Added saveChanges code.
(I removed my own logging methods off the callbacks.)

```
manager.saveChanges()
            .then(saveSucceeded)
            .catch(saveFailed)
            .finally(saveFinal);

        function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
            console.log(saveResult);
        }

        function saveFinal(saveFinal){
            console.log(saveFinal);
        }

        function saveFailed(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
```

`saveFailed` receives the TypeError above, while `saveFinal` is undefined.

result object:

```
{  
   "d":{  
      "__metadata":{  
         "id":"http://localhost:8080/targit2/targit2.svc/Applicationlocations(applicationID=2332,locationID=6)",
         "uri":"http://localhost:8080/targit2/targit2.svc/Applicationlocations(applicationID=2332,locationID=6)",
         "type":"targit2.Applicationlocation"
      },
      "applicationID":2332,
      "locationID":6
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how do you create your entity in javascript...

Comment: Can you show the JSON response to the POST message?

Comment: @parthicool05 I use `manager.createEntity('Entityname', {allEntityProperties});
As I mentioned, the items are correctly saved to my databse...

Comment: When the issue will come after saveChanges called or before saveChanges calling

Comment: Can you show your code snippets?...

Comment: @parthicool05 It happens, when server communication is finished (the stack above shows, that it happens within a saveSuccess callback) breeze seems to have problems updating its own Entities...

Comment: @parthicool05 updated the question body containig some code.

Comment: What is your version of angular.js and q.js

Comment: @parthicool05 angular is version 1.2.16, breeze.angular should not use Q.js but $q instead...

Comment: I have to check and inform u later..

Comment: Hi how to save your data you save the data using post method right...

Comment: @parthicool05 For sure, as stated in the question a use POST on a $batch function.

Comment: You don't have to use post method it is the problem for this issue..

Comment: So,  how could I change that? I have not found such a configuration option within breeze...

Comment: can you Show your java script codes and class file codes and then I will solve the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breeze uses [datajs](http://datajs.codeplex.com/documentation) to convert data to and from the OData formats.  I suspect that datajs is having trouble coping with the response from Olingo.

I think Olingo originated with SAP, and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344362/breezejs-savechanges-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-statustext?rq=1) describes a problem with that server.